# Which power supply should I get?

Tags: hardware

So I am using my raspberry pi 3 for octoprint as well as using it to run a Nas with an attached usb HDD.

I am getting the undervolt/overtemp icon on octoprint and get "throttled=0x50000" when running vcgencmd get_throttled.

I don't think the pi is overheating as it's sitting at around 50C but it might not be getting enough current/voltage from the power supply.

My main question is whether I should get the raspberry pi 4 power supply and use an adapter to micro usb because it provides 3A or the raspberry pi 3 one that only provides 2.5A?

I feel like the raspberry pi 4 one would be better as it allows more current for the pi to use and someday I might upgrade to a pi 4 anyway.

**Update: The PI3 one works great :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the official 5.1Volt 2.5Amp micro usb power supply for a Pi3.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-universal-power-supply/

Comment: Even though the pi 4 one can provide 500 ma more current?

Comment: What power supply are you using now? Adding an adapter could cause voltage drop.

Comment: Currently im using a tablet charger and its obviously not providing enough, ill get the pi3 one because theres no way im gonna be able to find out about the adapter without buying it and i dont want to waste money. Thanks

Comment: @ToXIcDev "*ll get the pi3 one...*". This is suggested by the answer so please accept it with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.